# Check equality of n numbers in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to check whether all numbers are the same. The values are coming from different columns. The signiture should allow to put any amount of columns (like the `COALESCE(...)` method)

```
SELECT equality(42, 42, 42)
```

should return `true` and

```
SELECT equality(23, 42, 133)
```

should return `false`.

Is there a nice way to code this?

At time i did it like this:

```
SELECT (x1 = x2 AND x2 = x3);
```

But i hope there is a more elegant way.

Comment: @njk - Unless I'm missing something, we don't have two queries here.

Comment: Thats not a duplicate...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Use this:

```
SELECT GREATEST(42, 42, 42) = LEAST(42, 42, 42)
```

Comment: Nopes. Check out different values.

Comment: He means `SELECT GREATEST(42, 42, 42) = LEAST(42, 42, 42)`

Comment: @RaphaëlAgneaudeSelve Thanks. It was my mistake. Updated it.

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario Yeah buddy, sorry. Typo there. So, it checks for both greater and lesser value in the set to be equal.

Comment: +1  Great insight here.   I think the only failure might be if one also wishes to return true if all values are `NULL` where even the [`NULL`-safe equality operator `<=>`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_equal-to) won't help because it would also return true if the set contains at least one `NULL` and at least one non-`NULL`.  I suspect the solution in such a case would be `SELECT COALESCE(GREATEST(42,42,42), 42,42,42) <=> LEAST(42,42,42)`.